# Check if there is a Controller by a given name at runtime

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I've have existing functionality in an MVC 5 app for checking if a controller exists based off of a name, and if so, redirect them off to that controller with the same Action. But I'm struggling to adjust my logic to accomplish the same task in MVC Core.

In MVC5, I could do this with `ControllerFactory`, and call `CreateController(requestContext, controllerName)` with a new RequestContext, the controller name, and just examine the result.

In MVC Core, It appears that the `ControllerFactory` is still involved, and there is still a method for `CreateController`, but its signature is `CreateController(ActionContext context)`

Passing in an empty ActionContext results in an error about the ControllerTypeInfo not being set (I'm assuming for looking it up in something like the `ControllerFeature` collection), but if I had that, I wouldn't need to do any of this because I'd already have enough to determine if a Controller existed.

Is there something else I can use, or request from the the ServiceContainer, in order to determine if there is a controller by a specific name available?

Comment: You could use reflection but that would be slower.  I suspect the way you are trying to go about it is probably the better direction but I figured it was worth mentioning reflection.

Comment: If I could find the source code MVC uses to resolve a Controller name to an instance of the ControllerTypeInfo, that'd work too, but I haven't had much luck sifting through source code yet.

Comment: But the controller you'd be looking for would be in your own dll, right?

Comment: True, but if I use reflection then I'm making the assumption that the convention used to register controllers (using the 'Controller' suffix) will never change. But that CAN change with the modularity of MVC Core, and then my reflection would be wrong. That's why I was hoping to use the existing features of MVC to query the information it should already have for routing requests, to determine if it has a certain controller. Reflection might work in a pinch, but I'm really hoping to find a way to do it using MVC.

Comment: I have logic for checking if a Controller or a View exists in MVC5, but with MVC Core, I have only worked out a way to check if a View exists. Controller checking still eludes me.

Comment: I've chased so many rabbits down holes on this one. I thought maybe ApiExplorer or ApplicationModel might have the details I need, but for the life of me I can't find any way to get an instance of them from inside of a controller action. They don't be seem to be registered with the DI container, and the providers that are used to populate one look like they are called only once when the application starts? So there must be an instance floating around the internals of MVC **somewhere**.